# Given functions $\alpha_t$ and $\beta_t$ from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb C$ help me examine when this limit doesn't exist

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

$\alpha_t, \beta_t : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb C$ are two continuous functions with

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\beta _t = 0$$ and

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \alpha _t = 1$$

and $|\alpha_t| = 1, \forall t \in [0,1]$. We may assume these functions are differentiable in $[0,1]$. What are the conditions for

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\beta_t}{1-\alpha_t}$$

to exist?

EDIT: people are saying we can use L'Hospital in this case, so if:

$$-\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\beta'_t}{\alpha'_t}$$

exists can we say $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\beta_t}{1-\alpha_t}$ exists?

Comment: Apply L'Hospital...

Comment: @RushabhMehta can we do it for complex functions?

Comment: Yes, L'Hopital's Rule is applicable to complex valued functions also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume both functions to be differentiable, then you can write
$$\begin{split}
\alpha_t &= 1+ \alpha \cdot t + o(t)\\
\beta_t &= \beta \cdot t + o(t)
\end{split}$$
for some complex numbers $\alpha=\alpha_t^\prime(0)$ and $\beta=\beta_t^\prime(0)$.
The ratio you are considering can be rewritten as
$$\frac{\beta_t}{1-\alpha_t} = -\frac{\beta}{\alpha}+o(1)$$
and therefore, if you assume both $\alpha_t$ and $\beta_t$ to be differentiable at $t=0$, the limit will always exist, unless $\alpha^\prime(0)=\alpha=0$

Comment: is the only way for this to not happen if $\alpha = 0$?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I modified my answer to reflect that.

Comment: yeah that makes sense